# Using multicol with includegraphics in latex article

Tags: graphics, multicol

I am using `multicol` with `includegraphics` in latex article. Below is the sample code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \centering
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{square}}
        \caption{Square Image}
        \columnbreak
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=11.4em]{tall}}
        \caption{Tall Image}
    \end{multicols}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Below is the generated PDF:
[image]

Notice that the images are not placed properly. Also, the right margin is much more than left margin.

Comment: Does `width=\columnwidth` help?

Comment: It is much better than earlier. However the right hand margin is still much more than left hand side. Any clue?

Comment: That is normal: the inner margin has to be roughly half the outer margin, because when you open a book, you see `two` inner margins side to side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interesting approach with `multicol`, however, see if `tabularx` is more handy in your case:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Square Image}
&       \hfil
        \includegraphics[width=11.4em,valign=t]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Tall Image}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
or
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Square Image}
&       \hfil
        \includegraphics[width=11.4em]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Tall Image}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```